# JDO not storing time information in Date, only stores the day

Tags: java, google-app-engine, date, timestamp, jdo

I am using Google App Engine with Java, JDO for persistence. 
I have my `Activity` object with `timestamp` declared as Persistent and of type `java.util.Date`.

```
public class Activity ...
{ ...
  @Persistent
  private Date timestamp;
...
}
```

All Activities stored in the database are seen with correct dTate but time information is always zero. e.g Thu Sep 09 00:00:00.

In some other SO post (not related to google-app-engine though), I read we should use java.sql.Timestamp instead of Date in some cases, but GAE only [supports](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/dataclasses.html#Core_Value_Types) java.util.Date.

One solution is always there to use 'long' to store the time information, but is there any better/preferred way to do this ?

Comment: Not sure if GAE support Calendar? Try this one instead, Date is deprecated and its use is discourage.

Comment: @Pawel No, Calendar is not supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far I could not get any solution. I replaced the 'Date' with 'long' (indicating time in milliseconds) as mentioned in the question.